# React on small media query show the native mobile keyboard

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I am using material ui textfield to search a query and show the list of items below.
My problem is when i have small screen (mobile view) i have the same functionallity as web, and i wanna change it.

For example i dont want to "click" in query text to move on but i want to "click" on search icon mobile keyboard and make the search as the image below

[image]

**Textfield Component**

```
        <TextField
          autoFocus
          placeholder="Start typing to search"
          fullWidth
          id="fullWidth"
          value={query}
          onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
          InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="start">
                <SearchIcon />
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
          }}
        />
```

Comment: Try input type="search" instead of type="text".

Comment: @AravindPrabash thanks for the hint. The first problem was resolved as you said.
But now if i click the searchIcon in mobile nothing happeds, it needs the onClick function inside the Textfiled component??

Comment: Or is better to wrap it with <form></form> and put onSubmit method ?

Comment: Try wrapping it with a form and put an onSubmit, so it should work not only for search icon, but for the enter button as well. There might be phones without search key.